# How to count dates lower than other date group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
install       type   id       date
2021-11-01    main   a1        NA
2021-11-01    main   a2     2021-11-02
2021-11-01    main   a3     2021-11-02
2021-11-01    main   a3     2021-11-02
2021-11-02    down   b4     2021-11-05
2021-11-03    main   b7     2021-11-05
2021-11-04    main   a3     2021-11-05
```

I want to group this data by date and type and count unique id's with same type which have install lower than date. So desired result is:

```
    date       type      count    
2021-11-02     main       3
2021-11-05     down       1
2021-11-05     main       4
```

For `2021-11-02     main` its 3 because there are 3 unique id's with same type and lower date (a1, a2, a3), for `2021-11-05     down`  its only b4, for `2021-11-05     main` its a1, b7, a2, a3

How to do that? I know about groupby and nunique(), but I dint know how to write condition of install being lower than date.

P.S.

I need it to calculate retention value for each date and type group

Comment: Are you intending to count the NA in both dates?

Comment: @Chris what do you mean? I am counting unique id's, there is no NA as you can see

Comment: Aren't all of the `main` types lower than `2021-11-05`?  Why count `a1` and not `a2`?

Comment: @Chris yeah right, I edited it

Comment: `2021-11-02` has only two unique ids `('a2', 'a3')`

Comment: @sammywemmy and also a1. it has same type and install is lower than date

Comment: thing is date for `a1` is Null, and you can't tell if install is lower than null. I am probably misinterpreting the question. @Chris answer should suffice

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a groupby, since you count some records more than once.  I'm not sure how to avoid looping here, iterates over every pair of type/date and filters and takes nunique.

```
out = []
for index, group in df.groupby(['date','type']):
    d, t = index
    out.append({'date':d, 'type':t, 'count':df.loc[(df['install']<d) & (df['type'].eq(t))]['id'].nunique()})
pd.DataFrame(out)

         date  type  count
0 2021-11-02  main      3
1 2021-11-05  down      1
2 2021-11-05  main      4
```